# Error going full screen flash applet (NPObject)

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I've googled about for an hour or so now and can't find a solution which works, I have a flash player and I need to full screen it using JavaScript, I can get the JavaScript to send commands (my volume function works) but my full screen one always returns:

```
Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
```

Most posts referring to this are solved with adding the as3 security line, for me, that's not the problem

```
Security.allowDomain("mydomain.com");
```

```
function fScreen() {
    if (stage.displayState== "normal") {
        stage.displayState="fullScreen";
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    } else {
        stage.displayState="normal";
    }
    call('console.log', 'okok');
}
```

When I just output to the console it goes through fine. Any other ways of going fullscreen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added alloweFullScreen in the embed and object tags? 
To use full-screen mode, you need to add a new parameter to the  and  tags in your HTML. Here is an example of the  and  tags with full screen enabled:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,18,0" width="600" height="400" id="fullscreen" align="middle"> 
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /> 
<param name="movie" value="fullscreen.swf" /> 
<param name="bgcolor" value="#333333" /> 
<embed src="fullscreen.swf" allowFullScreen="true" bgcolor="#333333" width="600" height="400" name="fullscreen" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
 </object>
```

Check out this article: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html